# Amazon iPhone app search view explanation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a new system for search. My problem is I need to do an initial search by querying a remote db. Then I'd like to be able to do a local search with the results. The simple solution is to have 2 search bars but that would look awful :P

So I checked out amazons app. When you go to search you are immediately presented with the resultsView (that's what I call it) but a search box comes down from the top and a white background fades out the resultsView. You are then able to perform your query to their DB and the view immediatley disappears and you are back to the results.

Does anyone have any ideas how they got the search bar to come down from the top? Is it another view or just an animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they added a search bar in a `UIView` and animate the `UIView` from top to bottom. I also think they actually present a new controller that animate the search view and present a `tableView` for the search result from 0 opacity to 1.